# Check registry write permission

Tags: delphi, winapi, registry

Is there an API call to check if the current user has write access to the registry?
We have an older program which sadly stores several critical values in HKLM that must be updated when the application starts and ends (there is a service which picks these up).
Elevating the user is not an option and running as admin is also not an option.
We just need to check if we can write (and no, writing a key and catching the exception is not what im looking for).

Comment: can you run that HKLM-addicted program in a virtualized environment like SandBoxie ?

Answer (score 2):

The Win32 API function that you ask for is [`AccessCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815.aspx). However, it's not the easiest function to use.

The commonly accepted way to do what you are attempting is to write the value without performing any checks beforehand. If the write fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, then you don't have rights. It's better to ask forgiveness than permission, certainly when it comes to Windows security!

Comment: As you say, it's a bit tricky to use. If you have some code for checking if registry access is granted on the current user, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't. There is loads around. Search for AccessCheck. Expect most of the code to be in C++ or C#. Why are you rejecting the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` option? That is trivial to implement and guaranteed to be correct. Remember that your question was "Is there an API call?"

Comment: Holy cow, my boss uses that quote all the time, this is the first time I've seen anyone else use it :-)

Comment: Given what OP really wants, this Q should be tagged `[teh-codez-plz]` :-)